# Connecting Excel 2013 to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, excel-2013

I am working on a user tool that is created in Excel 2013. The tool is used to simulate physical processes and report the answer. I am also working on a database created in MS Access which contains experimental data in multiple tables.

I was trying to add another facet to the excel tool by creating a form where the user will be able to query the database from excel and populate the excel sheet with relevant data from the database which can then be used to compare experimental data against the simulation output.

To do this I added the "Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library" reference.

I tried adding the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library" but I get "Error in loading DLL" message

When i write my code i get compile error because excel does not recognise

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
```

despite having the MS Access 15.0 Object Library reference loaded.

any help to resolve this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try again with a reference to "Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library" (instead of DAO 3.6).  If it accepts that, `DAO.Database` will be recognized.